Dark energy and conservation of energy in General relativity
i know that conservation of energy in general relativity has been discussed multiple times here at PE, a popular explanation on the topic is Sean Carroll's blog "Energy is not conserved" where he explains why energy is/isn't conserved depending on the definition.
Now when it comes to dark energy which is said to be increasing in amount because as the universe expands the density of dark energy remains the same everywhere, Carroll says it can be argued that energy is conserved because

“there’s energy in the gravitational field, but it’s negative, so it exactly cancels the energy you think is being gained in the matter fields”

Now conservation of energy is explained as energy not being created or destroyed, but isn't still the case that new dark energy is still being created out of nothing even if is offset by negative gravitational energy so that energy is "conserved", thus violating the "energy cant be created or destroyed" part of the conservation law?

Energy conservation is a consequence of time translation invariance. In general, spacetimes (such as cosmological spacetimes) do not have time translation invariance, and hence energy is not conserved.
